# DynaviewEngine causes NullPointerException in PrimeFacesContext

Tags: primefaces, servlet-filters, prettyfaces

I'm running Prettyfaces 3.3.3 and Primefaces 4.0

When browsing a page which is mapped by a dynaview

```
org.primefaces.context.PrimeFacesContext.release
```

is called twice, which causes a NullPointer at

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().release();
```

Because is current instance is already released.

The left Image is the stack for the first call, the right is the stack of the second call.

[image: The left Image is the stack for the first call, the right is the stack of the second call.]

It seems that the Problem ist that DynaviewEngine.java:101 triggers an

```
facesContext.getExternalContext().dispatch(viewId);
```

Which leads to a second filter chain, which calls PrimeFacesContext.release.

The page is displayed properbly but the exception in the log is annoying.

Comment: stacktraces in code please, not in images

Comment: Hi there. My first thought is that you are using an outdated version of PrettyFaces. The current version is 3.4.1.Final. Try upgrading and see if that helps.